# How to concatenate last quarter files in a folder using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge, directory, concatenation

I'm trying to merge last quarter file in a directory using python .I have tried using pandas to merge it but it is not possible to use it.

Comment: What is "last quarter file"? Please share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: last quarter mean mar-jun